# Как удалить объект при помощи составного ключа в Entity Framework, если такое возможно?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ProgrammerId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    public virtual ProgrammerProfile Programmer { get; set; }
    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }

    public int KnowledgeLevel { get; set; }
```

Comment: А как вы пробовали и что не получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим что у Вас есть такая сущность:

```
public class EntityProg 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ProgrammerId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    public int KnowledgeLevel { get; set; }

    public virtual ProgrammerProfile Programmer { get; set; }

    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }   
}
```

Предположим, что у вас в контексте имеется `DbSet` таких сущностей:

```
public virtual DbSet<EntityProg> EntityProgs { get; set; }
```

---

Предположим, что вы хотите удалить одну такую сущность по двум ключам `programmerId` и `skillId`:

```
// попытаемся найти сущность по двум ключам
var record = context.EntityProgs
  .SingleOrDefault(_ => _.ProgrammerId == programmerId && _.SkillId == skillId);

// если такая сущность найдена, удалим
if (record != null) 
{
    context.EntityProgs.Remove(record);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Также, имеется метод удаления коллекции `RemoveRange`, с помощью которого можно удалить сразу несколько сущностей. Всё просто, сначала нужно найти сущность в контексте, вытащить ее оттуда и положить в переменную, а затем передать в нужный метод DbSet-а (`Remove` или `RemoveRange` - в зависимости от того, нужно удалять одну сущность или несколько).

---

В качестве альтернативного решения можно пойти и другим путем (с использованием `Attach` метода, чтобы не делать выборку и не слать SELECT перед удалением):

```
var entityProg = new EntityProg
{
    ProgrammerId = programmerId,
    SkillId = skillId
};

context.EntityProgs.Attach(entityProg);
context.EntityProgs.Remove(entityProg);
context.SaveChanges();
```

---

Но и это еще не всё, можно пойти дальше и пометить сущность в качестве удаленной через ее состояние, для примера:

```
var entityProg = new EntityProg
{
    ProgrammerId = programmerId,
    SkillId = skillId
};

context.EntityProgs.Attach(entityProg);
context.Entry(entityProg).State = EntityState.Deleted;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Ссылка на источник: [Delete a single record from Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17723658/5275890)

Полезные ссылки для изучения:

- [DbSet.Remove](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.remove?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbSet_Remove_System_Object_)
- [DbSet.RemoveRange](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbSet_RemoveRange_System_Collections_IEnumerable_)
- [DbSet.Attach](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.attach?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)
- [DbContext.SaveChanges](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext_SaveChanges)

Comment: Ну и стандартная рекомендация использовать Attach, чтобы не слать select перед удалением (к тому же у нас первичный ключ и объект заведомо существует в одном экземпляре)